# Easiest way to echo/return every value from mysqli with the same 'version'

Tags: sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

As the title says. I'm trying somehow to display every value from database with the same Patch_No as the $_POST variable.

```
$sql = "SELECT champion FROM champions where Patch_No = \'".$_POST[\'patch\']."\'";
                $x=0;
                if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
                    while($row = $result->fetch_row()){
                        echo $row[x];
                        $x+=1;

                    }

                }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCLvi.png

so actually I'm trying to explain all champion names with the same patch.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting only the `champion` column so it means you only have only 1 column that you can access with `$row[0]` nothing else, the index is not the row number.

Also learn to prepare your query:

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$sql = "SELECT champion FROM champions where Patch_No = ?";

if ($result = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
    $result->bind_param('d', $_POST['patch']);//double

    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        printf ("champion = (%s)\n", $row[0]);
    }

    $result->close();
}

$conn->close();
?>
```